# Content Slider by Ennui: how to keep navigation arrows visible

Tags: jquery, css

I have been using [Ennui's Content Slider](http://ennuidesign.com/demo/contentslider/) quite a lot lately, since it is easy to use and edit.

I can't figure out how to make the left-handed arrow appear both initially and throughout the slideshow, and when you get to the end of slideshow, the right-handed arrow to stay visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```
.cs_leftBtn, .cs_rightBtn {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

But the problem is that if the user clicks the left arrow at the beginning of the slideshow or the right one at the end, the slideshow won't work anymore until the page is refreshed.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the help much appreciated, yeah is a shame, will see if its really that important with my client, thanks again though!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also remove

```
if(b.attr('class')=='cs_leftBtn') {
    var thisBtn = $('#'+thisInstance+' .cs_leftBtn');
    var otherBtn = $('#'+thisInstance+' .cs_rightBtn');
} else {
    var thisBtn = $('#'+thisInstance+' .cs_rightBtn');
    var otherBtn = $('#'+thisInstance+' .cs_leftBtn');
}
if(m==0||m==x) {
    thisBtn.animate({ 'opacity':'0' }, o.speed, o.easing, function() { thisBtn.hide(); });
}
if(otherBtn.css('opacity')=='0') {
    otherBtn.show().animate({ 'opacity':'1' }, { duration:o.speed, easing:o.easing });
}
```

and change

```
.find('.cs_leftBtn')
    .css("opacity",0)
    .hide()
    .end()
```

with

```
.find('.cs_leftBtn')
    .hide()
    .animate({ 'width':'show' });
```

(js/jquery.ennui.contentslider.js)

But I don't know if you will also have the problem that the slideshow stops working...